# Values coming into Dropdown box as one line

Tags: javascript

I have a Dropdown box, Which is getting filled by values from mySQL database, here is the part of the script that I am using to fill the drop down.

```
var details = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(details);
for ( i = 0; i < details.aaData.length; i++) {
console.log(details.aaData[i].id);
$('select#package-id option').append(details.aaData[i].id);
}
```

and here is HTML,

```
<select name="package" name="package-id" id="package-id">
        <option></option>
</select>
```

But the dropdown shows the values as 1234 where as I am expecting them as,

1

2

3

4

Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Changing This:

```
var details = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(details);
for ( i = 0; i < details.aaData.length; i++) {
console.log(details.aaData[i].id);
$('select#package-id option').append(details.aaData[i].id);
}
```

to this:

```
var details = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(details);
for ( i = 0; i < details.aaData.length; i++) {
console.log(details.aaData[i].id);
$('select#package-id').append("<option value='"+details.aaData[i].id+"'>"+details.aaData[i].id+"</option>");
}
```

it looks right now like you may be creating a bunch of option inside the blank option.

Comment: So I have to delete the <option></option> tag inside the HTML?

Comment: That did the trick, though I tried something like this but I was missing value property I guess. Thanks!

Comment: You can delete the empty option. If you don't you may have to handle it in your validation. if you wanted to get rid of the empty entry, then change the above to call $('select#package-id').children().remove(); first. This will get rid of any children of the select before you add more.